# Sync Gmail, Google Contacts, Google Calendar with Microsoft Exchange

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, exchange, imap

At my work we only use Microsoft Exchange. As I hate Outlook and much prefer Google's services, I'd like to be able to sync my email, calendar, and contacts to a Gmail account.

It looks like Google shut down their Google Sync service for Gmail accounts earlier this year: http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2716936.

They are recommending IMAP, CalDAV, and CardDAV. I'm having trouble even setting up IMAP to work with Exchange. Is this the best way to go or is there a better solution?

Comment: I hate Outlook too. That said, you're probably better off using Outlook, or perhaps something like Thunderbird with DavMail Gateway. Do you really want to be "that one guy" in your organization? Speaking as "that Emacs guy", also "that Thunderbird guy" and "that guy who does all his dev work in VMs", it can be a tough row to hoe...

Comment: The best you can do currently is export the Outlook calendar and import it back into Google Calendar.  You can also publish your Outlook Calendar to a WebDAV Server which can do the syncing.  Sadly Google Calendar will not support even CalDev by the end of 2014.  The best solution is a third-part add-on that does the syncing through the official Google Calendar API,

Comment: I was able to find the following Outlook Addon that appears to do what you want: https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=4262+17155367427235402467&pli=1

Answer (score 1):

For email unless you can get pop access to your various folders (which Google can poll) I am not aware of an elegant solution. Setting up Auto Forward would probably not be allowed in a normal company setting. Beyond that you're probably going to need code.

For calendar, contacts, tasks and notes the solution I found was to use the memotoo platform - http://www.memotoo.com/#sync_website

This combines synchronising to/from just about any address/calendar combinations - some are smoother to set up than others though.

It provides an exchange compatible interface and will sync calendars and contacts to/from Outlook/Windows or Exchange server.

You can set up memotoo to connect as you to your exchange server (warning: your company might not like this happening) as well as sync to google. You can set up directions (always from outlook and out to google, for example, or both ways etc.) and you can limit to certain tags or categories synchronised.

Note: If you had already at some synced manually through export/import, you will risk duplicates happening the first time, which memotoo (and gmail) can then detect and fix, but it is a time waste we dont need. If I had to do it again I would wipe one of the address books to have a cleaner start.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [GO Contact Sync Mod](http://sourceforge.net/projects/googlesyncmod/) will do the job for you. It is an open source app that does the following for you (according to its website):

- Synchronize your contacts between Microsoft Outlook and Google Mail.
- Contact Categories and Contact Photos Automatic Synchronization
- Backup your Outlook Contacts to the Cloud Software free-of-charge
- Synchronize your Exchange contacts as well as your contacts in a PST
- File Synchronize your contacts with Windows Phone 7 (WP7), iPhone and
- Android over the air through Google

The only downside I see is that it doesn't work "in the cloud", i.e. you have to install it on every PC where you are running Outlook in order to make sure that all new contacts are synced. And even then you will miss changes that you made through the Exchange Web interface until you turn on a computer with Outlook (and GO Contact Sync Mod) installed. I'm giving it a try anyway.